# Using fwrite on file descriptor / Convert file descriptor to file pointer

Tags: c, linux, sockets, serialization, fwrite

Lately, I've been working on some small data serialization demos. However, I was wondering how to transfer binary data from a structure into a file descriptor.

I am aware that the only (simple) way to do this is through `fwrite` (if `write` does this, then please say so), so is there either:

A) An `fwrite` call to use on file descriptors?

or

B) A way to create a `FILE *` around an existing file descriptor/socket, like the opposite of `fileno`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [fdopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen).

Comment: This kind of answer makes me wish I didn't have to wait 8 more minutes to accept it.

Thanks!

Comment: Short and sweet. I'd add more but if you had problems or questions using fdopen, now that would be another question. :)

Comment: Nah, man pages tend to be really helpful. The problem, sometimes, is finding them. Besides, errno.h is usually verbose enough.

Answer (score 1):

There are answers for both A) and B):

A) Yes, `write()` for a file descriptor is analagous to `fwrite()` for a file pointer:

```
if (fwrite(&foo, sizeof foo, 1, fp) < 1)
     /* Not successful */
```

or

```
if (write(fd, &foo, sizeof foo) < sizeof foo)
    /* Not immediately successful */
```

B) As [Matt Joiner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305284/using-fwrite-on-file-descriptor-convert-file-descriptor-to-file-pointer/3305296#3305296) says, `fdopen()` is the inverse of `fileno()`.

Comment: Short `write` need not mean unsuccessful. The only failure case is when it returns -1. Certain types of fd's only support certain write lengths at a time, so in general you'll have to loop until all the data is written. For this reason, `fdopen` and `fwrite` are more convenient (they'll do it for you).

Comment: @R. I'm a little confused as to how to use fdopen to write over a socket. As far as my understanding goes, a socket is a file descriptor so I can use `FILE* sf = fdopen(socketDescriptor, "w")`, since I wish to write. Then I can use `fwrite` on `sf` to write to the socket. But after I'm done with all of this, do I use `close` on `socketDescriptor` or `fclose` on `sf`? I'm new to this so any advice is welcome.

Comment: @jmlopez: You should use `fclose(sf)` to close the stream, and this will close the underlying socket itself.

Comment: Note: If you want to be able to close the `FILE` without closing the fd, use `dup` on the fd and `fdopen` the duplicate.